# Unable to get data from React App to Node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

So Am unable to make a search function i want to get a variable from search field and show the results that matched but am constantly getting this error
variable undefined when i try to console.log it in the node server
Edit-- i have already changed the axios.post to axios.get

```
app.get(`/search/`, (req, res) => {

let {name} =req.body
var Desc = name
console.log(name)
var Op= Desc+'%'
const q = "SELECT * FROM taric where Description LIKE ? ";
con.query(q,[Op], (err, search) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.json(err);
  }
  console.log(search);
  return res.json(search);
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

As you can see you are making `POST` request from frontend where as there is no `POST` request route to handle your request. As you have make route of `GET` for fetching the data from backend you need to make `GET` request from frontend as well. So you need to do as below:

```
axios.get(`your_endpoint_route_goes_here`);
```

instead of this:

```
axios.post(`your_endpoint_route_goes_here`, requestBodyObj);
```

Comment: thanks i got it ,the error is resolved, but now am getting { name: undefined }

Comment: I assume you may have not pass the request body. But In case if you pass request body with GET method proxy issue may occur. If you want to pass request body you can go with different method like POST method. If you want to pass data with GET method you can pass data or id as query params. Hope this link will helps you: https://www.thecodebuzz.com/http-get-delete-request-body-guidelines/ . In this link you can see about Proxy Issue.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP methods are not the same.
You are using app.get in the server while triggering a POST call from your client.

axios.post <-----> app.get
(There is no route for POST call which client is expecting)

Comment: yeah thanks the error is resolved . but i am still getting a empty set; if i print that variable it is showing { name: undefined }